# Get post object in shortcode function

Tags: shortcode

I have to display a post from another page (index.php), so my code is

```
$section_id = 16;
$section_home = get_post($section_id);

setup_postdata( $section_home ); 
the_content();
```

This post (with ID 16) has a few shortcodes inside. I can't access the $post object inside of the shortcode functions, for example I tried

```
function tp_sc_flipcoin($atts,$content = null){
    global $post;
    var_dump($post);
    return "";
}

add_shortcode( 'tp_flipcoin', 'tp_sc_flipcoin' );
```

and it displays the post with ID=1, I also tried:

```
function tp_sc_flipcoin($atts,$content = null){
    var_dump($post);
    return "";
}

add_shortcode( 'tp_flipcoin', 'tp_sc_flipcoin' );
```

and in this case it displays NULL.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign the $post yourself. [See the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) that `setup_postdata` won't do it for you. Try this:

```php
global $post;

$section_id = 16;
$post = get_post( $section_id );
setup_postdata( $post ); 

the_content();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! For those who have the same problem, `global $post;` is necessary in the shortcode function.